No java runtime was found error : TripleA game on linux
I am using Linux Mint 22 and I installed TripleA from apt package manager , then it gave me this error :
me@me-desktop:~$ triplea
[warning] /usr/games/triplea: No java runtime was found

I actually have java installed on this system and write various java programs as a student . This is the output :
me@me-desktop:~$ java --version
openjdk 21.0.4 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu224.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu224.04, mixed mode, sharing)

And here is all the java packages installed in my system :
me@me-desktop:~$ apt list --installed | grep openjdk

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

openjdk-21-jdk-headless/noble-updates,noble-security,now 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-21-jdk/noble-updates,noble-security,now 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04 amd64 [installed]
openjdk-21-jre-headless/noble-updates,noble-security,now 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-21-jre/noble-updates,noble-security,now 21.0.4+7-1ubuntu2~24.04 amd64 [installed]

I have also set the JAVA_HOME in the /etc/environment .
What should I do to fix this problem ?

I think the game is bundled with (and requires) java 11. ( https://github.com/triplea-game/triplea/blob/master/docs/development/README.md )

@Yorik Can I do that while not deleting jdk 21 from my system ? On windows I know there is the path variable but how do I do that on linux ?

I don't actually know. My first thought is to cd to the game folder before invoking the game. They do have a forum. I saw someone saying they blew away their java installs, but obviously you can't do that. Might jump to the linux stack and ask about multiple java runtime version coexistence
